# Interception of http/https requests in fiddler is not working from Azure Function?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-functions, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1, fiddler

I have an azure function, running locally. it sends out a post request to a remote endpoint that looks something like `https://organization-name.somesoftware.com/api/v1.3` it seem to be captured by fiddler but i can not look at the request header or the body payload. I am not sure whether the request is intercepted correctly by fiddler

here is the screenshot from fiddler

[image]

Comment: fiddler + https ? I just remembered that if we wanna use fiddler to capture https requests, we need some configurations. Maybe [this document](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/firefoxhttps) can help you.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is due to Azure Function Execution timeout, by the time fiddler receives and starts debugging the request the Azure Functions gets timeout. You can solve this by increasing the Azure Function time out.

You can check the following document for more information and to increase the timeout.

[Azure Function Timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout).

Alternatively, you can try moving to different hosting plan for the Azure Function and also increase the time out at the same time.

[Azure Function Premium Plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-premium-plan?tabs=portal).

[Azure Function Dedicated Plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dedicated-plan).